# Custom Font in View Pager in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am developing demo application in which I am using view pager. Now I want to know that can we change the text style of Title displayed in view pager.

Please give your suggestions on it.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working demo

```
TextView txt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.custom_font);
```

and then change your font

Something like this:

```
switch (position) {
     case 0:
            v = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(cxt).inflate(R.layout.lcmeter, null);
            TextView txt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.custom_font); 
            Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Chantelli_Antiqua.ttf");  
            txt.setTypeface(font); 
            break;
     }
```

Comment: do not do this that way - your app will memory leak due to the bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9904