# Adding multiple fonts for a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

How to add a custom font to ViewPager.

I am creating a book reader app which has to display  Sanskrit and English script.
How can i achieve that any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819531/custom-font-in-view-pager-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it in a web view and load it like html loads. You can use additional fonts by adding font file in assets and you simply want to add it in css for the html file.